# How to get the last record added to the database using sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In particular, I am using flask-sqlalchemy in case that is relevant.
I looked up the solution online but that returned an error, here is the code I wrote:

```
last_post = Post.query.order_by(Post.id.desc()).first()
```

This is the error I got:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'desc'
```

What can I do to get the last record that added to the database in the Post table?

Answer (score 0):

You should use it this way

```
last_post = Post.query.order_by(desc(Post.id)).first()
```